# Getting an SQL Error while combining aggregate function with list items

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, aggregate-functions

I've only started learning SQL recently. We're using MS Access (2010, in my case). No the task is that I have to list how many workers from a list called "radnik" work in different company locations (marked as "brod"). So I wrote this down:

```
SELECT brod, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM radnik
ORDER BY brod;
```

There are about 18 people in the list, all of them have values of 10,20,30,40 or 50, so it should make a table, for instance, like:

```
brod | count
10   | 5
20   | 9
...
```

I get, the error, though:
*You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'brod' as part of an aggregate function.*
Obivously, I'm doing something wrong, but I'm still very new to SQL. I'd **very** much appeciate if someone could explain to me why this doesn't work and how it could be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT brod, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM radnik
GROUP BY brod
ORDER BY brod;
```

In short: whenever you're using an aggregate function like `COUNT`, all other selected columns need to be in the `GROUP BY` clause as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   brod, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM     radnik
GROUP BY brod
ORDER BY brod;
```